# PyQGIS: remove filter from new layer

Tags: pyqgis

I'm currently writing some code which creates a new layer from the selected features of another layer.

```
layer_4 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('layer_1')[0]
iface.setActiveLayer(layer_4)
layer_2 = iface.activeLayer()
selected_2 = layer_4.selectedFeatures()
crs_2 = QgsProject.instance().crs().authid()
selection = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=" + str(crs_2), "selection", "memory")
new_features_2 = []

for feat in selected_2:
    new_features_2.append(feat)

selection.dataProvider().addFeatures(new_features_2)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(selection)
```

This seems to work, however the points are not displayed in the new layer and when I'm checking the attribute table it says that all elements are filtered. Why? And how do I remove the filter?

Comment: You may use `new_features_2.append(QgsFeature(feat))` instead of `new_features_2.append(feat)` to be sure you do not share features between layers

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly why your code is not working although seen some logic issues. IMO, there is a simpler way to do the same as what you want to achieve using Processing algorithms. There is one processing algorithm named `Extract selected features` within `Vector General` in the "Processing Toolbox" panel. Using it through Python/PyQGIS, the following should do what you expect

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject
import processing

selectedLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('layer_1')[0]

if len(selectedLayer.selectedFeatures()) > 0:
    result = processing.run("native:saveselectedfeatures", {
        'INPUT': selectedLayer,
        'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
    })
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(result['OUTPUT'])
    # If you want to unselect, uncomment below
    # selectedLayer.removeSelection()
else:
    print("No selected features for the layer")
```